# Can I use One bone to Play an action? Need help for using action modifire

Tags: rigging, armature, actions

I have a bat model and I made an action that Frame 0 is Bat with open wings and On frame 24 bat is in Resting Mode and Made this with help of all the bones that bat has.
Now I want make a seprate bone / a Controll bone and I want when i rotate this bone or scale it or whatever, This action play.
For Example I want to just keyframe this bone from frame 1 to 24 and this bat animation ( action ) plays.
Thank you guys for answering. Really I need becouse my client ask me to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You could try it with the *Action* bone constraint, but you need to give the constraint to each bone that is animated. Create your animation, create the bone that will trigger the animation (I've called it Ctrl). Give the constraint to one of your bone. Once you've set the constraint, select the other bone(s) that you want to constrain, shift select the bone that you've already constrained, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (you need to have the *Copy Attribute* addon activated) > *Copy Bone Constraint* (or on top of the constraint, down arrow > *Copy to Selected*).

As for the settings, choose the controller bone as *Target*, under *Target* choose the movement of the controller that will trigger the action (*X Location* on *Local Space* for example), under *Range Min* and *Max* choose the amplitude (here how many units on X) that the controller needs to do to animate the whole action, and under *Frame Start* and *End* set the length of the action that will be played. Of course you'll need to keyframe the controller.

[image]

Result:

[image]

Comment: Just a heads up, you can copy bone constraints without any addons just by using "copy constraints to selected bones" operation.

Comment: Oh yes you're right, in the Action constraint

Comment: Thank you for replying. 
This action Im talking about involved all the bones not just one bone so I can connect to that. This action is made of leg bones, Wing bones and head bone

Comment: Hello, as I said if it involves several bones, you just need to copy the constraint for the other bones as explained in my answer